# Nginx only shows welcome page

Tags: nginx

I'm trying to set up a simple virtual host, serving only static files. Trouble is, directing the browser to (in this case) `jorum.dev` displays the default nginx welcome page, as opposed to `jorum.dev/index.html`.

Nginx was installed using Homebrew on Mac OS X Mountain Lion.

### hosts

```
127.0.0.1       jorum.dev
```

### jorum.dev

```
server {
    listen          80;
    server_name     jorum.dev;

    location / {
        root        ~/Sites/jorum;
        index       index.html index.htm;
    }
}
```

### nginx.conf

```
worker_processes  1;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    sendfile        on;

    gzip            on;
    gzip_disable    "msie6";
    gzip_min_length 1100;
    gzip_vary       on;
    gzip_proxied    any;
    gzip_buffers    16 8k;
    gzip_types      text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/rss+xml text/javascript image/svg+xml application/x-font-ttf font/opentype application/vnd.ms-fontobject;

    server_tokens off;

    client_max_body_size    4096k;
    client_header_timeout   10;
    client_body_timeout     10;
    keepalive_timeout       10 10;
    send_timeout            10;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: where do you put 'jorum.dev' block? in nginx.conf?

Comment: No, it's in `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-available/jorum.dev`, symlinked to `/usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/jorum.dev`.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Missing includes in **nginx.conf**

```
include /usr/local/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
```

http://wiki.nginx.org/CoreModule#include

Comment: Thank you! After adding the include I got a regular 404 error, which in turn got me to trying out writing out the full path to the root, rather than using `~` for the home folder. Works now.

Comment: where to put include?

Comment: @HerilMuratovic in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf

Answer (score 33):

the debian/ubuntu nginx package comes with a `default` sites-available that takes over the default host dispatch. Simply remove the default link and it should load your site instead.

---

another gotcha, the debian/ubuntu nginx package also comes with a default index value for the default server in the default site that reads:

```
index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
```

I've had the file `index.nginx-debian.html` show up in my www root directory, which took precedence over the cgi locations.

---

nginx has a verbose test mode that can be used to dump the entire configuration as parsed by nginx, which you can sanity check against your expectations.

```
nginx -T
```

Comment: for those not so familiar unix, is it ok to do this? $ mv site-enabled/ site-enabled_backup/

Comment: @greenhouse IIRC the sites-* locations are declared in `/etc/nginx/nginx.conf`, I think it would be safe to move the location like you do so long as where nginx looks for configs still exists (if it even cares). you can always run `sudo nginx -t` to check if your changes are valid

Comment: what I did was simply `unlink sites-enabled/default`.

Comment: Thanks - this saved me from a few hours of research. The default being sym-linked from sites-available to sites-enabled was capturing my reverse proxy setup. Removing the sym link worked.

Comment: I have spent 3 days to solve this, your solution saved me weeks of googling. Thanks so much

Comment: Thanks, I simply uncommented the line `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` in the configuration file and it worked!

Comment: You're my hero. Thank you! I changed the order of index.php to front of index.nginx-debian.html in default conf file then the problem solved. But I don't know why it worked properly before.

Answer (score 15):

remove **default.config** from **/etc/nginx/sites-available/** and **/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/** and restart nginx

```
rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/default
rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default
sudo nginx -t
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

Comment: This is perfect, I was trying to do this from within a docker container and this is exactly what it needed.  However, from within the docker container, can't use systemctl, so `nginx -s reload` worked.

Answer (score 9):

For other people coming to this thread and already tried @freestyler's answer, but still getting the default nginx screen, try to rename the `default` file located in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/` to something like `default.txt`. I recommend **not** deleting the file, since it helps you explain what to do in your next `.conf` file.

Comment: If I do this, nginx does not start any more due to an error. But this answer lead me to the solution for me: I commented out the line `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*` in the default config and it worked.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was that I had forgotten to bind the site to IPv6 and my PC was on an IPv6 connection.

I simply added `listen [::]:80;` to the server object, before I only had `listen 80;`.

That made the Nginx show the site also if connections were made using IPv6.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe unrelated, but hopefully will help people dropping on to this question...

Sometimes people forget to add the symlink in the `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled` pointing to the site config in the `/etc/nginx/sites-available`.

something like:

`ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-availabe/mysite.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mysite.com`

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to the location block:

```
index index.html index.htm
```

For example:

```
location / {
    …
    index  index.html index.htm;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that I'd initially had the website at a subdomain, and when regenerating the certbot certificate to get it to also work at a new domain, I'd not added the new domain name redirects in server section, adding as follows fixed for me:

```
server {
    if ($host = domain_1.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    if ($host = domain_2.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name domain_1.com domain_2.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you tuning up html site, you can to delete `default` nginx config

`rm /etc/nginx/sites-available/default && rm /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default`