# https connection not working on nginx (aws), only ip:port working

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, gunicorn

New nginx user here. I am running a flask app with gunicorn on AWS account. The following config in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flaskapp` works from my laptop at address `1x.xxx.xx.45:80`

```
  server {
    listen 80;
    server_name 1x.xxx.xx.45;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
  }
```

but when I change to following settings by using public ipv4 DNS address, it only showed default page of nginx, not my app. (this issue is in second/after attempts; my first attempt with with same aws/inbound rules had worked fine with https url. I used same aws/security-group afterwards but no success)

```
  server {
    listen 443;
    server_name ec2-xx-xx-xx-45.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
  }
```

Afterwards I unlinked `/sites-available/default` as described in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460935/nginx-only-shows-welcome-page) and I don't see anything on that url. I tried other answers as well in that but no use. I am missing something obvious to others.

Eventually I want to fire multiple apps on aws-ec2 and connect to them from outside via https for different tasks.

---

Output for `nginx -T`

```
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful
# configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
    # multi_accept on;
}

http {

    ##
    # Basic Settings
    ##

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;
    # server_tokens off;

    server_names_hash_bucket_size 128;
    # server_name_in_redirect off;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ##
    # SSL Settings
    ##

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    ##
    # Logging Settings
    ##

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    ##
    # Gzip Settings
    ##

    gzip on;

    # gzip_vary on;
    # gzip_proxied any;
    # gzip_comp_level 6;
    # gzip_buffers 16 8k;
    # gzip_http_version 1.1;
    # gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

    ##
    # Virtual Host Configs
    ##

    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}


#mail {
#   # See sample authentication script at:
#   # http://wiki.nginx.org/ImapAuthenticateWithApachePhpScript
# 
#   # auth_http localhost/auth.php;
#   # pop3_capabilities "TOP" "USER";
#   # imap_capabilities "IMAP4rev1" "UIDPLUS";
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:110;
#       protocol   pop3;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
# 
#   server {
#       listen     localhost:143;
#       protocol   imap;
#       proxy      on;
#   }
#}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-image-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-http-xslt-filter.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_http_xslt_filter_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-mail.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_mail_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/50-mod-stream.conf:
load_module modules/ngx_stream_module.so;

# configuration file /etc/nginx/mime.types:

types {
    text/html                             html htm shtml;
    text/css                              css;
    text/xml                              xml;
    image/gif                             gif;
    image/jpeg                            jpeg jpg;
    application/javascript                js;
    application/atom+xml                  atom;
    application/rss+xml                   rss;

    text/mathml                           mml;
    text/plain                            txt;
    text/vnd.sun.j2me.app-descriptor      jad;
    text/vnd.wap.wml                      wml;
    text/x-component                      htc;

    image/png                             png;
    image/tiff                            tif tiff;
    image/vnd.wap.wbmp                    wbmp;
    image/x-icon                          ico;
    image/x-jng                           jng;
    image/x-ms-bmp                        bmp;
    image/svg+xml                         svg svgz;
    image/webp                            webp;

    application/font-woff                 woff;
    application/java-archive              jar war ear;
    application/json                      json;
    application/mac-binhex40              hqx;
    application/msword                    doc;
    application/pdf                       pdf;
    application/postscript                ps eps ai;
    application/rtf                       rtf;
    application/vnd.apple.mpegurl         m3u8;
    application/vnd.ms-excel              xls;
    application/vnd.ms-fontobject         eot;
    application/vnd.ms-powerpoint         ppt;
    application/vnd.wap.wmlc              wmlc;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kml+xml  kml;
    application/vnd.google-earth.kmz      kmz;
    application/x-7z-compressed           7z;
    application/x-cocoa                   cco;
    application/x-java-archive-diff       jardiff;
    application/x-java-jnlp-file          jnlp;
    application/x-makeself                run;
    application/x-perl                    pl pm;
    application/x-pilot                   prc pdb;
    application/x-rar-compressed          rar;
    application/x-redhat-package-manager  rpm;
    application/x-sea                     sea;
    application/x-shockwave-flash         swf;
    application/x-stuffit                 sit;
    application/x-tcl                     tcl tk;
    application/x-x509-ca-cert            der pem crt;
    application/x-xpinstall               xpi;
    application/xhtml+xml                 xhtml;
    application/xspf+xml                  xspf;
    application/zip                       zip;

    application/octet-stream              bin exe dll;
    application/octet-stream              deb;
    application/octet-stream              dmg;
    application/octet-stream              iso img;
    application/octet-stream              msi msp msm;

    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document    docx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet          xlsx;
    application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation  pptx;

    audio/midi                            mid midi kar;
    audio/mpeg                            mp3;
    audio/ogg                             ogg;
    audio/x-m4a                           m4a;
    audio/x-realaudio                     ra;

    video/3gpp                            3gpp 3gp;
    video/mp2t                            ts;
    video/mp4                             mp4;
    video/mpeg                            mpeg mpg;
    video/quicktime                       mov;
    video/webm                            webm;
    video/x-flv                           flv;
    video/x-m4v                           m4v;
    video/x-mng                           mng;
    video/x-ms-asf                        asx asf;
    video/x-ms-wmv                        wmv;
    video/x-msvideo                       avi;
}

# configuration file /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/flaskapp:
  server {
    listen 443;
    server_name ec2-xx-xx-xx-45.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8000;
    }
  }
```

And `ls /etc/nginx/sites-available/` is `default` and `ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/` is `flaskapp`

Comment: Hi Navin, what is the output of `nginx -T`?

Comment: Also what is the output of `ls /etc/nginx/sites-available/` as well as `ls /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/`?

Comment: Do @ to notify users - I wasn't aware you edited, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling `/etc/nginx/sites-available/default` completely.

```sh
mv /etc/nginx/sites-available/default /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.bak
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```

And/or adding `include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*.*;` after `include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;` in your `nginx.conf`, which seems to be missing.

Comment: sorry, trying one or both did not work

Comment: So you renamed `default`, restarted `nginx` and included `sites-enabled` - what is the output? 404 or default page?

Comment: I get 'This site can't be reached`.. `refused to connect` when tried with https-dns-url

Comment: @navin Read: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-instance-hosting-unresponsive-website/