# Nginx shows only Welcome page after changing server_name from IP adress to domain

Tags: django, nginx

I use Nginx as Reverse Proxy for a Django project with Gunicorn.

After following this tutorial from Digital Ocean [How To Set Up an ASGI Django App](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-an-asgi-django-app-with-postgres-nginx-and-uvicorn-on-ubuntu-20-04) I was able to visit my project through the server IP adress in a browser with http.

In the next step I followed the [How To Secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-20-04) tutorial from Digital Ocean. Now the site was available with http:// and https:// in front of the IP adress.

To redirect the user automatically to https I used code from this tutorial.[5 Steps to deploy Django](https://medium.com/@saijalshakya/5-steps-to-deploy-django-application-using-nginx-reverse-proxy-gunicorn-and-ssl-certificate-52990194b4c5)

The outcome is the following file in /etc/nginx/sites-available:

```
# Force http to https
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name EXAMPLE_IP_ADRESS;
    return 301 https://EXAMPLE_IP_ADRESS$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 80; # manged by Certbot
    server_name EXAMPLE_IP_ADRESS;

    # serve static files 
    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location /static/ {
        root /home/user/projectdir;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }

    listen 443 ssl;
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/fullchain.pem;

    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/www.example.com/privkey.pem;

    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;

    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}
```

The redirect to https is working fine, so I assume the changes I made according to the last tutorial are okay.

After the tests with the EXAMPLE_IP_ADRESS as server_name went well I have changed the server_name to my domain in the form [www.example.com](http://www.example.com)

When I type the domain in the browser the only result is the Nginx Welcome page. So the connection to the server is successfull but Nginx is loading the wrong server block.

Answer (score 0):

After searching for hours I came across this [Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14460935/nginx-only-shows-welcome-page). Here the answer of ThorSummoner worked for me. The comment by mauris under this answer to unlink the default file in the sites-enabled was the command I needed.

`unlink sites-enabled/default`

(I posted this Q&A because I searched hours for the solution and hope this is reducing the search time for others having a Django project too with the same problem)